# Accessing Pixel data using FreeImage

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using freeimage.so for my android project,How can I access pixel data,ie RGB components of a picture taken from the SD card,I had been searching on this topic for quite a long time..any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I got the solution,complete manual in PDF form from the below URL:-

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgraphics.stanford.edu%2Fcourses%2Fcs148-10-summer%2Fdocs%2FFreeImage3131.pdf&ei=_0ANUPrFL4vRrQfL0IHJCA&usg=AFQjCNG3TTEnjbAktNJwDMujoWOqZkV7jw